# how to show tabbar in my whole application screen? it disappears in next activity

Tags: android, tags

Android

I have created Tabbar in bottom side in android. It works well for one screen but when I  move to anther activity it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

```
host= (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        host.setup();


        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        // Create an Intent to launch the first Activity for the tab (to be reused)  
        Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, activity1.class);  

        spec = host.newTabSpec ("FirstGroup").setIndicator("activity1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagename)).setContent(i);  

        host.addTab(spec);  
 TabHost.TabSpec spec;


        // Create an Intent to launch the first Activity for the tab (to be reused)  
        Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, activity2.class);  

        spec = host.newTabSpec ("FirstGroup").setIndicator("activity2",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagename)).setContent(i);  

        host.addTab(spec);
```

u have to use your activity in tabhost, dont start activity independently

Comment: ye dude i try above code it works well but i need more detail.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html go for this, & dnt forget to up my point, thx

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the tabbar to one activity only, so it's obvious it will disappear for the rest of the activities. So, you have to put the tab bar stuff on each activity. What I'd do is putting the tabbar on a separate XML file (e.g. layout/tabbar.xml)... and use the `<include>` tag on the other XML layouts in order to avoid repeating the same code twice or more.

Comment: ye dude i try above code and it works well but i need more detail.i give u detail on my app there is a five tab in bottom side.i call tabactivity direct from login screen so it display login page activity it works.when i click one tab it open its set activity but in the its settable activity it tabar disappears.help me dude its urgent....help

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
        public class Tab1ActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup
    {
        public static Tab1ActivityGroup group1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            group1 = this;

            View view = getLocalActivityManager()
                .startActivity("Tab1Activity", new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();

            replaceView(view);
        }

        public void replaceView(View v)
        {
            v.setFocusable(true);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            v.requestFocus();

            setContentView(v);
        }
    }




public class Tab1Activity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_one_activity);

    }


        View v = Tab1ActivityGroup.group1.getLocalActivityManager()
                    .startActivity("NewActivityFromTabActivity", intent)
                    .getDecorView();
        Tab1ActivityGroup.group.replaceView(v);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use THis to start the new Activity

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("tab1", new Intent(this,tab1.class)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
.getDecorView();

setContentView(view);
```